# How do I enter a numeric number in sequence in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a table that is sorted by clicking from larger to smaller values. How to make sure that the ordinal number of the value is always between 1 and 5 after sorting the table?

That is, the numerical order should always be between 1 and 5 and should not be sorted.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var $table = $('#simpleTable').stupidtable();
        $table.find('thead th[data-sort]').on('click', function() {
            $(this).eq(0).stupidsort();
        });
    });
```

```html
 <table id="simpleTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-sort="int">#</th>
                <th data-sort="int">int</th>
                <th data-sort="float">float</th>
                <th data-sort="string">string</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>18</td>
                <td>banana</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>95</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>coke</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>152.5</td>
                <td>apple</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>88.5</td>
                <td>zebra</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>195</td>
                <td>858</td>
                <td>orange</td>
            </tr> 
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stupidtable/1.1.3/stupidtable.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand what you mean. Are you asking for the first column to always show 1-5 in correct order, independent of which column you click?

Comment: `stupidtable` and `stupidsort` may not support sorting only a subset of columns while others remain static (I didn't see anything after a quick look at the documentation indicating that it does). If you want to number the rows in the table, you could number them programmatically in jQuery after the sort completes. That would be a short function.

Comment: @freefaller Yes, if you sort the tables, the numbers will not be displayed in order 52413, but they must always be in order 12345.

Comment: @lurker Can you please tell me how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never heard of - and therefore never used - [`stupidtable`](https://github.com/joequery/Stupid-Table-Plugin) but it doesn't look like there is a call-back event once the sorting has completed.

So instead, I've used a timeout as part of the `click` event.

The within the timeout finds all the `first-child` `<td>` elements, and uses the index of `each` to set the text of the element.

As the [`stupidsort` code](https://github.com/joequery/Stupid-Table-Plugin/blob/master/stupidtable.js#L98) does the sort 10-milliseconds after the client event, I've had to make it 20 in the code for it to work...

```js
$(function() {
  var $table = $('#simpleTable').stupidtable();
  $table.find('thead th[data-sort]').on('click', function() {
    $(this).eq(0).stupidsort();
    
    // After a short period, set the values
    setTimeout(function() {
      $table.find("tbody tr td:first-child").each(function(i, v) {
        $(this).text((i + 1).toString());
      });
    }, 20);
  });
});
```

```html
<table id="simpleTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-sort="int">#</th>
                <th data-sort="int">int</th>
                <th data-sort="float">float</th>
                <th data-sort="string">string</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>18</td>
                <td>banana</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>95</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>coke</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>152.5</td>
                <td>apple</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>88.5</td>
                <td>zebra</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>195</td>
                <td>858</td>
                <td>orange</td>
            </tr> 
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stupidtable/1.1.3/stupidtable.min.js"></script>
```